# Excluir parte do texto por delimitadores

Tags: php

Texto:

Exemplo [caption id="attachment_90" align="alignleft" width="400"] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[/caption]

Como excluir a toda expressão acima do texto.

Comment: Marquei como duplicata pq a solução já foi dada na outra, mas de qq forma o @KhaosDoctor pode editar a resposta dada se quiser complementar aqui também. Se faltar algum detalhe naquela, deixe comentário. Atenção especial ao 5º código, que me parece ser o que vc procura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vocẽ pode usar regex para remover. Se você está usando o PHP, pode usar o `preg_replace` (veja no [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)) com a seguinte expressão: `\[.*?\]`.

Dá uma olhada nesse exemplo aqui: https://regex101.com/r/zX6gM2/1

Comment: Obrigado. Quero retirar tudo, a regex que me passou tira apenas o que está entre []. Vou estudar o regex aqui. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Apesar de ter a duplicata, se quiser vc pode dar uma complementada com o caso que o @lelopes pediu (tem um exemplo na pergunta linkada acima, na resposta que eu dei, se precisar). Se der uma acertadinha pra pegar o conteúdo todo do caption, dá pra ganhar uns votinhos merecidos, e o lelopes pode marcar como aceita aqui.